# How to get active users list from firebase using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am using firebase for one to one, one to many chat and I want to show green dot with user who are currently active and red dot with users who are de-active or not logged in firebase.
is there any solution in js, I am using Firestore Database?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Firebase realtime database is a different database. Please tag your questions only with the products that your query is about.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Firestore, you need to follow the instructions for [Building presence in Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence).

As you will read in this documentation section, the Firebase Realtime Database has a native presence feature. Since you use Firestore, the solution is to use a Cloud Function to mirror the presence data from the RTDB into Cloud Firestore